# SQL Server selecting one record for a day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query which selects [orderdate] for sites in the last week.
I want to be able to select only one record for a given site in a day.
My solution is as follows:

```
select 
     SiteName
     , OrderDate 
from 
     Table1  
where 
     OrderDate >= dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd,-53690,getdate()-1)/7)*7,-53690)
```

,but when you look at the results, you will notice that for date 21st for site2 it gives two records.  I need to select only one.

```
SiteName..................OrderDate

Site1....................2014-04-21 16:00:37.650

Site2....................2014-04-21 16:00:39.697

Site2....................2014-04-21 16:00:39.697

Site3....................2014-04-21 16:00:35.180




Site1....................2014-04-22 16:00:46.113

Site2....................2014-04-22 16:00:50.817

Site3....................2014-04-22 16:00:53.163



Site1....................2014-04-23 16:00:50.993

Site2....................2014-04-23 16:00:53.193

Site3....................2014-04-23 16:00:55.727
```

** editing the question **

Hi, sorry this is much for complicated than simply inserting distinct.  Included below is the entire query, but I only initially included part of it for simplicity sake:

```
select distinct 
       SiteName 
       ,SUM(Case 
            When 
               OrderDate >= dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd,-53690,getdate()-1)/7)*7,-53690) Then 
                1
            Else 
                0 
            End
          ) as Completed 
from 
      table1 
where 
      CLIENT    in ('Site1','Site2','Site3','Site4','Site5','Site6','Site7') 
and 
      SiteName != '(Site8)' 
GROUP BY 
      SiteName 
order by 
      SiteName
```

i am only select 7 sites avoiding site 8
 the result is

SiteName..................Completed

Site1..........................3

Site2..........................4

Site3..........................3

Site4..........................3

Site5..........................3

Site6..........................2

Sit7...........................2

for site 2 the count should be 3 instead of 4 but despite using distinct the query is still adding 2 records for that date

Answer (score 0):

I can't debug it, because I have no access to SQL server, so it may not work exactly like this, but take it as an idea.

```
select SiteName, count(SiteName) from
    (
    select DISTINCT SiteName , OrderDate from Table1  where 
    OrderDate >= dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd,-53690,getdate()-1)/7)*7,-53690)
    )
group by siteName;
```

The inner select will remove the duplicities and the outer select will count how many times the site is there.

Comment: Hi, sorry this is much for complicated than simply inserting distinct.My bad i should have included the entire query but i only included part of it for simplicity sake, the full query is as follow select distinct SiteName
    ,SUM(Case When  OrderDate >= dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd,-53690,getdate()-1)/7)*7,-53690)
              Then 1
            Else 0 
            End) as Completed
from table1 where CLIENT in ('Site1','Site2','Site3','Site4','Site5','Site6','Site7')
and SiteName != '(Site8)'
GROUP BY SiteName 
order by SiteName i am only select 7 sites avoiding site 8

Comment: Please update the question with the full query... don't leave it here in a comment.

Comment: Thanks Michael, but the reason i used the loop for the count, because it takes care of the scenario where if there is no record for the site it still gives my 0 as count

Comment: I see. If you would like to filter out the 0 values, you can write another select around these two.

Answer (score 0):

```
select DISTINCT SiteName , OrderDate from Table1  where 
OrderDate >= dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd,-53690,getdate()-1)/7)*7,-53690)
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. Code only answers do not help anyone understand what you're doing.

Comment: @ckuhn203 : you are right, the only thing required in this case we have to add DISTINCT so the result is distinct. as you can see, in the example, for Site2, we have '2014-04-21 16:00:39.697' two times! take a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)